# MYSQL Select Min(Time) where date col is min(Date)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the Min(Time) where the Date is Min(Date) can someone point me in the right direction?

something along these lines but this doesn't work.

```
select Min(timecol) as MinTime from myTable where daycol = '1' and datecol = min(datecol)

daycol     datecol         timecol
   1     16/01/2019        08:30:00
   1     17/01/2019        01:30:00
   1     16/01/2019        12:30:00
   1     18/01/2019        12:30:00
   2     16/01/2019        08:30:00
```

Comment: What version of MySQL? (this matters)

Comment: ... and store dates and times as a single entity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT min(a.timecol), a.datecol, a.daycol FROM `timetable` a 
  WHERE a.datecol = (
      SELECT min(b.datecol) from `timetable` b
  )
```

This gets the 08:30 on 16/01/2019 row returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select timecol as MinTime from myTable where daycol = '1' order by datecol ASC limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT
    MIN( timecol ) AS MinTime
FROM myTable
WHERE daycol = '1'
AND datecol = (
    SELECT
        MIN( datecol )
    FROM myTable
    WHERE daycol = '1'
)
;
```

If you are running MySQL 8 or later (or any db supporting window functions) then:

```
SELECT
    daycol, datemin, timemin
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
      , MIN( datecol ) OVER (PARTITION BY daycol) datemin
      , MIN( timecol ) OVER (PARTITION BY daycol, datecol) timemin
    FROM myTable
) d
WHERE daycol = '1'
AND datecol = datemin
AND timecol = timemin
```

Comment: Did you want to use `PARTITION BY daycol, datecol` as `OVER` clause for the minimum `timecol`? Otherwise this gets 01:30:00 for the minimum time for `daycol = '1'`. As this time belongs to 2019-01-17, which is not the minimum date for `daycol = '1'`, your query returns the empty set.

Answer (score -1):

This gives you the Min of timecol where datecol is minimal.
select Min(timecol) as MinTime from myTable where datecol = ( select min(datecol) from myTable);

Make sure that timecol and datecol are of types DATE and TIME respectively.